# How to use scikit-learn's SVM with histograms as features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I wish to use scikit-learn's SVM with a chi-squared kernel, as shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/kernel_approximation.html#additive-chi-squared-kernel).  In this scenario, the kernel is on histograms, which is what my data is represented as.  However, I can't find an example of these used with histograms.  What is the proper way to do this?

Is the correct approach to just treat the histogram as a vector, where each element in the vector corresponds to a bin of the histogram?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an example of using an approximate feature map [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/plot_kernel_approximation.html#example-plot-kernel-approximation-py). It is for the RBF kernel but it works just the same.

The example above uses "pipeline" but you can also just apply the transform to your data before handing it to a linear classifer, as `AdditiveChi2Sampler` doesn't actually `fit` to the data in any way.

Keep in mind that this is just and approximation of the kernel map (that I found to work quite well) and if you want to use the exact kernel, you should go with ogrisel's anwser.

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn.svm.SVC` accepts custom kernels in 2 manners:

- arbitrary python functions passed as `kernel` argument to the constructor
- precomputed kernel matrix passed as first argument to `fit`and `kernel=precomputed` in the constructor

The former can be much slower but does not require to allocate the whole kernel matrix in advance (which can be prohibitive for large `n_samples`).

The are more details and links to examples in [the documentation on custom kernels](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels).

Comment: The OP apparently wants to use Andy's kernel approximations, which work differently (and would be used with linear learners).

Comment: Actually I am not sure whether OP wants a real kernel and use the SMO solver of libsvm on it or if OP wants to approximate the kernel expansion with non linear random feature mapping and then train a linear SVM such as SGDClassifier on those.